# Bootstrap reflow content at different sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know the basics of the Bootstrap 3 grid, including push/pull, but I haven't figured out a way to do a layout like this:

[image]

Basically I want the text block between the images at XS size, but then hoisted out into its own column as the window gets bigger. I know I could move the content around with javascript or something, but I'm looking for a way to do this in markup. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Float right at the min width and a clear left, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to do, but I'm not sure what you want to happen when the image height exceeds the text height. That occurs in my demo at `md` widths.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right text">
            <p class="lead">text text text tex...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pCq54/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two added classes:

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/piwoja/1/**

*http://jsbin.com/piwoja/1/edit*

**CSS:**

```
.clear-left {clear:left}
@media (min-width:768px){
  .pull-right-sm {float:right;}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Image 1" />
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right-sm">
            ... your text goes here long or short
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 clear-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Image 2" />
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Does the [`div.clearfix.visible-sm-block`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) approach not work?

Comment: @cvrebert : Didn't think of it since I'm so used to making my own stuff up if there is no class that is specifically clear:left. Will test.

Comment: @cvrebert: yep, but since he wants small and up this is better <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div> will correct.

Comment: @cvrebert: Not really -- clearfix hidden-xs works only if the text is shorter than the image. http://jsbin.com/piwoja/3/edit but clear:left works with variable text and image heights : http://jsbin.com/wavara/1/edit